# Converting Primitive int array to list

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem. There are  two arrays A of size n and B of size n+1. A and B have all elements same. B has one extra element. Find the element.

My logic is to convert the array to list and check if each element in B is present in A.

But when I am using the primitive arrays my logic is not working. If I am using

```
Integer [] a ={1,4,2,3,6,5};
Integer [] b = {2,4,1,3,5,6,7};
```

My code is working fine.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int [] a ={1,4,2,3,6,5};
    int [] b = {2,4,1,3,5,6,7};     
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(b));
    for(Integer i :l2)
    {
        if(!l1.contains(i))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }           
    }
}
```

And also My logic is O(n+1). Is there any better algo.

Thanks

Comment: Your logic is n*m, basically squared (n^2) because for each element of array you do search in the second array, in case of dictionary/map search it would be faster but in your case with lists is a n^2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason it is not working for primitive arrays, is that **Arrays.asList** when given an **int[ ]** returns a **List<Integer[ ]>** rather than a **List<Integer>**.

**Guava** has an answer to this in the [Ints](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/index.html) class. Is has an **asList** method that will take an **int[ ]** and return a **List<Integer>**

**Update**

```
int[] a = ...;
int[] b = ...;
List<Integer> aList = Ints.asList(a);
List<Integer> bList = Ints.asList(b);
```

The above will allow your code to work properly for int[ ] as it works for Integer[ ].

Check out [Ints API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: I modified my code as List<Integer[]> l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
      List<Integer[]> l2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(b));
      for(Integer[] i :l2)
      {
          if(!l1.contains(i[0].intValue()))
          {
              System.out.println(i);
          }           
      }

Comment: updated. Notice I am using Ints.asList NOT Arrays.asList. This is a Guava library function so you would need to include the guava jar.

Comment: Good find.  I used this in the past and it took me forever to find it again.  Keep in mind that there are similar methods in all of the corresponding classes - Longs, Floats, Doubles, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Calculate the sum of each array.  Sum(B) - Sum(A) will give you the extra element in B.

Comment: Nice. This assumes there is one and only one element that is different. But if that is the case it works nicely and is truly O(n)

Comment: for integers and longs, not necessarily for booleans, doubles, floats

Comment: @MatthewFarwell booleans would work too, both in the "+ is xor" interpretation and the "true is 1" interpretation

Answer (score 3):

The contains method of an ArrayList is in fact not so efficient. This allone has a runtime of O(n), so your algorithm has runtime O(n^2).

I suggest to put one array in a HashSet (with a contains() runtime of O(1)). You can leave the other array as it is and iterate through the array directly. Then your runtime is O(n).

**Update:**
From the [HashSet API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

I think the default Integer hash function fullfills the requirements.

Comment: Would it truly be O(n)? Since HashMaps conatins method is not exactly O(n). The O-ness depends on the number of elements vs. the number of buckets.

Comment: @John B : I believe since array has difefrent values there are no buckets will be created

Comment: @venje not necessarily true. Different values may have the same hashCode per the equals / hashCode contract. Although it might be a safe assumption that each int value has a unique hashCode (since hashCode) returns int, this would not be true of something like long and I don't think is a safe assumption. That being said I don't know that the O-factor is really the issue here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest because it would be a bit complex because of arrays concatenation operation, but another operations would take `O(n)`

1. Put both arrays into a single array
2. [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) items
3. All the same items will be self-removed and single element will be the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct two [`Set<Integer>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) objects from your two arrays, and then use [`removeAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to find the extra element.

P.S. Your method is not `O(n)` as you seem to think. For the overall method to be `O(n)`, each iteration of the loop has to execute in constant time; I leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out whether this is the case.

Comment: So what is the O? I am thinking O(n^2) (n-squared)

Comment: @aix I think my algo is O(n). because I am looping through all elements of B once. and by the time it finishes we are done. Am I wrong?

Comment: int [] a ={1,4,2,3,6,5};
  int [] b = {2,4,1,3,5,6,7};  
  Set<Integer> s1= new HashSet();
  Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet();
  s1.add(a);
  s2.add(b);
  s2.removeAll(s1);
     Object[] c = s2.toArray();
     System.out.println(c[0]);

Comment: @ravi it may be O(n^2) since `contains()` itself may be O(n), for example if using an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a single `Set<Integer>` object.  Since a Set can't have duplicate elements, add all of A, then you can use the Add function to find the one entry that returns true in B.  Nice and easy.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach is to use `int[]`, use Arrays.sort and merge the results. I suspect it homework, so I will leave the actual solution to yourself.  This is O(n * log(n)) but the constant is lower than using wrapper objects and sets.

If you know the range of values is limited, you can use a BitSet. This would detect more than one difference and still be O(n)

If you know there is one and only one difference, compare the sums as @rossum suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Only for those that are interested, solution typical to the logic of rossum. But in case wen we have big numbers then it could be possible to have some overflow issue.

The alg is simple, we start with w zero value and from once array we substract from another we add to it the elements, at the end we add our n+1 element.

This will work in O(n) (the n is n+1)

I assume that array b have more elements.

```
long result = 0;

for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result -= a[i];
    result += b[i];
}

result += b[a.length];
```

And in the result we have our difference.

EDIT:

Even better solution proposed by harold, where we don't need to worry about memory.

```
int result = 0;

for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result ^= a[i] ^ b[i];
}

result ^= b[a.length];
```

Comment: overflow doesn't matter, the result is still correct - or you could use XOR and have no overflow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an int array (not Integer), use IntStream:

```
int[] arr = {15, 13, 7, 4, 1, 5, 19, 18, 7, 7, 12, 15};
List<Integer> arrayList = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(arrayList);
```