# Boxing with Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, generics, collections

In the following examples:

```
class ZiggyTest2{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4,7};      

        List<Integer> li2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        li2 = Arrays.asList(a);     

    }
}
```

The compiler complains that that int[] and java.lang.Integer are not compatible. i.e.

```
found   : java.util.List<int[]>
required: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
                li2 = Arrays.asList(a);
                               ^
```

It works fine if i change the List definition to remove the generic types.

```
List li2 = new ArrayList();
```

- Shouldn't the compiler have auto-boxed the ints to Integer?
- How can i create a `List<Integer>` object from an array of ints using
  Arrays.asList()?

Thanks

Comment: define your array as Integer []a {1,2,4,5};

Comment: you could also have just done `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,7)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an int\[\] array to a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324633/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-a-list) see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530680/converting-primitive-int-array-to-list

Comment: You don't need to assign `new ArrayList<Integer>()` to li2 when you are discarding it again at the next line

Comment: Thanks guys. I was more interested in how boxing/unboxing would work in the above scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not support the auto-boxing of an entire array of primitives into their corresponding wrapper classes. The solution is to make your array of type `Integer[]`. In that case every int gets boxed into an `Integer` individually.

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 };
List<Integer> li2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : a) {
    li2.add(i); // auto-boxing happens here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Removing the generics make it compile, but not work. Your List will contain one element, which is the `int[]`.
You will have to loop over the array yourself, and insert each element in the `List` manually